# adding realm object with array

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i'm new to Realm and therefore i'm trying to test a Object however i keep getting the error below

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''NSArray' is not supported as an RLMObject property. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, RLMArray, or subclasses of RLMObject. See http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/api/Classes/RLMObject.html for more information.
```

**Object**

```
import RealmSwift
import CoreLocation

class Organization: Object {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var image: NSData = NSData()
    var locations: [CLLocation] = []

}
```

**Test in ViewDidLoad**

```
    let organ1 = Organization()
    organ1.id = 1
    organ1.name = "Statens Museum For Kunst"
    organ1.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "statensmuseum.jpg")!)!
    organ1.locations = [CLLocation(latitude: 50.6456604, longitude: 3.053486600000042)]

    // Persist your data easily
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(organ1)
    }
```

Comment: From the documentation : "Realm supports the following property types: Bool, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Double, Float, String, NSDate truncated to the second, and NSData.

You can use List<Object> and Object to model relationships such as to-many and to-one. Subclassing Object is also supported."

You cannot persist an Array this way, and I am not even sure you can persist `CLLocation ` objects.

You can do the trick by persisting the `longitude` and the `latitude` in two different `Double` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround to persist Location :

```
class Location: Object {
   var id: Int = 0
   var longitude: Double = 0
   var latitude: Double = 0
}

class Organization: Object {
   var id: Int = 0
   var name: String = ""
   var image: NSData = NSData()
   let locations: = List<Location>()
}
```

You can add a implement a constructor in `Location` which serialise   `CLLocation`.

```
 let location1 = Location()
 //set your Location's properties

 let organ1 = Organization()
 organ1.id = 1
 organ1.name = "Statens Museum For Kunst"
 organ1.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "statensmuseum.jpg")!)!
 organ1.locations.append(location1)
```

Comment: So how will i add a Location object to the locations list? Could u give an example of this?